# Why does sqlite3-ruby-1.2.2 not work on OS X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am running

- OS X 10.5,
- Ruby 1.8.6,
- Rails 2.1,
- sqlite3-ruby 1.2.2

and I get the following error when trying to rake `db:migrate` on an app that works find connected to MySQL.

> rake aborted!
>   no such file to load -- sqlite3/database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jamis has just released 1.2.4, and the comment history on that bug suggests that the fix is in 1.2.3 and later versions.  As a quick test, I did the following on an OS X 10.5 box with Ruby 1.8.6:

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

(verified version number of 1.2.4)

```
rails test
```

(used default `database.yml` with sqlite3)

```
cd test
./script/generate model Person name:string
rake db:migrate
```

Ran fine.  The error would have happened when sqlite3 was `require`d before the migration finished, so it looks like they've fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's a [bug](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=20533&group_id=254&atid=1043) with 1.2.2.  Just roll back to 1.2.1 with:

> gem install sqlite3-ruby -v=1.2.1

and that will fix the problem.